# Marshalling and Iterating a list of objects from Dllimport in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I need to use a DLL's provider api to get a list of USB specific devices. Help information shows following in C++ language:

```
DWORD apiGetUsbCompanions(PUSB_COMPANION_INFO* pCompanions, DWORD* pdwSize, DWORD* pdwEntries)
```

Parameters: pCompanions (in/out)  Buffer containing the list of companions plugged in  the Windows device.
pdwSize (in/out)  Size of pCompanions buffer as input. Required size as  output.
pdwEntries (out)  Number of USB_COMPANION_INFO entries  returned in pCompanions.

Struct:

```
typedef struct _USB_COMPANION_INFO 
{  
    TCHAR szPort[PORT_SIZE]; // COM port 
    BOOL fActivated;  // Flag indicating whether the device is  activated 
    TCHAR szName[MAX_NAME_SIZE]; // Name of the companion
} USB_COMPANION_INFO;

typedef USB_COMPANION_INFO* PUSB_COMPANION_INFO;
```

Implemented before function in C# is like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class USB_COMPANION_INFO
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = PORT_SIZE)]
   public string szPort;             //COM
   public bool fActivated;          //  Device connected/in use
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_NAME_SIZE)]
   public string szName;             //COM
}

[DllImport("apiutilities.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int apiGetUsbCompanions([In, Out] USB_COMPANION_INFO pCompanions, ref int pdwSize, ref int pdwEntries);
```

I tried to get list by using this implementation:

```
USB_COMPANION_INFO list = new USB_COMPANION_INFO();
int pdwSize = 0;
int pdwEntries = 0;
int result = apiGetUsbCompanions(list, ref pdwSize, ref pdwEntries);
```

result value is 8 (I'm not sure but maybe is not enough memory), pdwSize is equal to 516, pdwEntries is equal to 0 and list have nothing.

Sample code from provider in C++ is as follows:

```
void SampleFunc(void) 
{  
    DWORD dwRet, dwSize, dwEntries;  
    USB_COMPANION_INFO pCompanions = NULL;   
    dwSize = 0;  
    dwRet = apiGetUsbCompanions(pCompanions, &dwSize, &dwEntries);  
    if (dwRet == ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY) 
    { 
        if (dwSize != 0) 
        {  // Allocate memory 
            pCompanions = (USB_COMPANION_INFO)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSize);  
            if (pCompanions != NULL)  
            {    
                dwRet = apiGetUsbCompanions(pCompanions, &dwSize, &dwEntries);   
                if (dwRet == ERROR_SUCCESS)   
                {    // Handle companions list    
                    for (DWORD i=0;i<dwEntries;i++)    
                    {     
                        // Handle pCompanions[i]    
                    }  
                }   

                HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pCompanions);  
            } 
        } 
        else 
        {  // No paired companions 
        } 
    } 
    else if (dwRet == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) 
    { // Bluetooth adapter is disabled 
    } 
    else 
    { // Undefined error 
    } 
}
```

I need to get List of USB devices in C#.

Thanks

Comment: What does the documenation say a return code of 8 means? does it specifically say that means ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY?

Comment: Documentation refers to C++ implementation, so says: Return value: ERROR_SUCCESS is returned in case of success and pCompanions contains the list of plugged companions. The number of companions in this list is indicated by *pdwEntries. ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY is returned if pCompanions is NULL or if its size is not large enough to contain all the plugged companions,  *pdwSize contains the size of the buffer to be allocated. If *pdwSize equals zero it means that no companion is plugged.

Comment: Well, you need to look at the .h file that came with the SDK and see what those values are defined as.

Comment: refers to winerror.h that says: ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY
8 (0x8) Not enough storage is available to process this command, so I guess I have to allocate memory according C++ sample, but I not know so much how to do it and iterating.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution:

```
public List<USB_COMPANION_INFO> GetUsbCompanions()
{
            USB_COMPANION_INFO compInfoUSB = new USB_COMPANION_INFO();
            List<USB_COMPANION_INFO> usbCompanions = new List<USB_COMPANION_INFO>();

            int pdwSize = 0;
            int pdwEntries = 0;
            int result = 0;

            pdwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(USB_COMPANION_INFO));
            result = apiGetUsbCompanions(compInfoUSB, ref pdwSize, ref pdwEntries);
            // Retry getting data info if Name is null or empty (Sometimes it fails getting information). Only apply for USB.
            if (pdwEntries > 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(compInfoUSB.szName))
            {
                // Reset communication to force to stop service
                StopCommunication();
                result = apiGetUsbCompanions(compInfoUSB, ref pdwSize, ref pdwEntries);
            }

            if (pdwEntries > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pdwEntries; i++)
                {
                    usbCompanions.Add(compInfoUSB);
                }
            }

            return usbCompanions;
 }
```